# Question about period and frequency

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, orbital-motion, centripetal-force

In the context of uniform circular motion, I have been so informed that period ($\tau$) is properly measured in seconds; and that frequency ($f$) in inverse seconds. Why is this the case? Wouldn't the measure for 1 period properly be considered as *seconds per cycle*? My current notion of a period holds true that a period is the rate of how many seconds it takes to describe a complete cycle; And that being the case, it should be so measured as *seconds per cycle*. And it is also a consequence of this fact that frequency should be measured in *cycles per second*. Could someone explain me where my reasoning is flawed if it at all is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What unit does cycles have? Itself? Do you want to add SI units for every countable thing? For people per square mile, do you want “people” to be an SI unit? For atoms per cubic meter, do you want “atoms” to be an SI unit?

Comment: Period is the amount of time it takes to go through one cycle. Frequency is the number of times one can go around and around within a fixed time interval. So for example, the *period* of the Earth's revolution around the sun is 365 *days*, and the *frequency* of the Earth's revolution around the sun is 1 *per 365 days*.

Comment: It's usually assumed that a complete cycle/revolution/repetition is meant, you can look up various definitions of the word and you can see they do use the word cycle (and sometimes they don't) and you can use that if you please and no one would really mind.

Comment: Would you not say: "the period of the Earth going around the Sun is approximately 365 days" and/or "the time it takes the Earth to complete one revolution about the Sun is approximately 365 days" because period is the time it takes to complete one revolution.?

Comment: The of period is [Hz] Herz cycle per second

Comment: @Ghoster That's a very bad comment. There's nothing wrong with naming units, but that's a completely different issue from how to think about cycles, which is a surprisingly subtle topic.

Comment: @DanielSank I trust that we are in agreement that the [current SI standard](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf) does not have cycle or cycles as a base unit or derived unit. Nor is it one of the “non-SI units that are accepted for use with the SI”. I was trying to explain why I think this is, in a simple way. How would *you* explain its omission?

Comment: @DanielSank The standard has this, and only this, to say about the use of “cycle”: ‘Note that in some countries, frequency values are conventionally expressed using “cycle/s” or “cps” instead of the SI unit Hz, although “cycle” and “cps” are not units in the SI.’

Comment: @DanielSank To me, the SI standard is perfectly clear “how to think about cycles”: Don’t use them as a unit. Because they aren’t one.

Answer (score 1):

Period is seconds per cycle and frequency is cycles per second.  If you convert frequency to angular frequency ($\omega =2 \pi f$), then units convert to radians per second.  One cycle is $2\pi$ radians.  A radian is a "unitless" unit often expressed as meters per meter.  This is why formulas for frequency (f) always have a $2\pi$ in them.  One place you don't see this is $v=f\lambda$.  This is because wavelength is meters per cycle rather than just meters.

Comment: It's tempting to reason as in this answer, but it's kind of wrong because in expressions like $\exp(i \omega t)$ we'd have to conclude that the argument of the exponential function has dimensions of radians, which is problematic.